# Not working an Update query as I wish

Tags: mysql

Hi I want to update a table with the values of another but do not how to do it.

I have tried this but it is not working.

```
UPDATE tblagendamiento SET
CodigoAgenda = 
(select tmptable.CodigoCita from tmptable where tmptable.id = tblagendamiento.id);
```

And this is the error:

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Comment: The error message is the answer to why your update does not work. Because `select tmptable.CodigoCita from tmptable where tmptable.id = tblagendamiento.id` returns more than one 1 row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually getting an error because your subquery is returning more than one row. I think you can achieve this simply using an `INNER JOIN` query

```
UPDATE tblagendamiento a
INNER JOIN tmptable b
ON a.id = b.id
SET a.CodigoAgenda = b.CodigoCita
```

Comment: You can't join without a `from` statement. It should be `update ... from ...`.

Comment: @Denis i missunderstood your question, can you please explain?

Comment: Your statement is invalid SQL and yields a syntax error, no? Or does SQL actually allow that?

Comment: Cool. Learning things every day. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The message is telling you that there is more than one row returned by your subquery. Assuming you don't want to use a random value (which you can do by appending `limit 1` to the query), it means your where clause is not selective enough.